# How to make a dynamic log in userform in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a login UserForm that the credentials will loop in a range in cells. the name of my worksheet containing the credentials is "Admin"

This the code I made but it is a hardcoded one

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1.Text = "Admin" And TextBox2.Text = "Admin123" Then
    Sheets("Interface").Select
    Sheets("Menu").Visible = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Menu").Select
    Sheet6.User.Enabled = True
ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "User" And TextBox2.Text = "User123" Then
    Sheets("Interface").Select
    Sheets("Menu").Visible = True
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Menu").Select
    Sheet6.User.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

I am expecting to have a dynamic log in form having its credentials in a worksheet

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1.Text = "Admin" And TextBox2.Text = "Admin123" Then

Sheets("Interface").Select
Sheets("Menu").Visible = True
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Sheets("Menu").Select
Sheet6.User.Enabled = True
ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "User" And TextBox2.Text = "User123" Then

 Sheets("Interface").Select
Sheets("Menu").Visible = True
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Sheets("Menu").Select
Sheet6.User.Enabled = False
End If

end sub

Comment: that is the full code

Comment: Do not post additional information in the comments. Always add it to your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have something like the below. Please note the following. The below code assumes you have a list of users stored in the Admin sheet in the A column with their equivalent passwords adjacent to them on the SAME ROW. You can adjust where necessary. You can also wrap this in an additional `For Loop` if you don't want to exit the sub straight away when encountering an error. The below code is not tested but I assume you can get the principle across.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rUser As Range
    Dim chk As Range

    'assuming you have 100 users and store their user names in the A column
    'also assuming that you have their equivalent passwords adjacent in the SAME ROW
    Set rUser = Sheets("Admin").Range("A1:A100")

    For Each chk In rUser
        'find the username
        If TextBox1.Text = chk.Value Then
            'find the matching password
            If TextBox2.Text = chk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                'your code here

            Else
                'error handling
                MsgBox "Error: You entered the incorrect password, please try again!", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        'error handling
        If chk.Row = 100 Then
            MsgBox "Error: Could not match your User Name, please try again!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next chk

End Sub
```

Additionally you do not necessarily need to use a `For Each` loop, and you can use a simple `For` loop. You can also add a dynamic `lRow` to count the last row of your users.

---

**EDIT: OP requested division between Admin and User checks.**

See below code to allow for the different code. This is only one method you can use. This method uses 2 separate lists for user names and passwords. Assuming you have your ADMIN usernames in column A of the Admin sheet, and the USER usernames in column C of the Admin sheet, with their respective passwords adjacent to the usernames on the same row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rUser As Range, rAdmin As Range
    Dim chk As Range

    'assuming you have 100 users and store their user names in the A column
    'also assuming that you have their equivalent passwords adjacent in the SAME ROW
    Set rAdmin = Sheets("Admin").Range("A1:A100")
    Set rUser = Sheets("Admin").Range("C1:C100")

'//---Check Admin first
    For Each chk In rAdmin
        'find the username
        If TextBox1.Text = chk.Value Then
            'find the matching password
            If TextBox2.Text = chk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                'your admin code here

            Else
                'error handling
                MsgBox "Error: You entered the incorrect password, please try again!", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next chk

'//---Admin not found - continue to user check
    For Each chk In rUser
        'find the username
        If TextBox1.Text = chk.Value Then
            'find the matching password
            If TextBox2.Text = chk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                'your user code here

            Else
                'error handling
                MsgBox "Error: You entered the incorrect password, please try again!", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        'error handling
        If chk.row = 100 Then
            MsgBox "Error: Could not match your User Name, please try again!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next chk

End Sub
```

Additionally, another method you can use is to simply add onto the original post. You can add a third column and call it Designation, where you define whether they are a USER or an ADMIN. See the below code for this method:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rUser As Range
    Dim chk As Range

    'assuming you have 100 users and store their user names in the A column
    'also assuming that you have their equivalent passwords adjacent in the SAME ROW
    Set rUser = Sheets("Admin").Range("A1:A100")

    For Each chk In rUser
        'find the username
        If TextBox1.Text = chk.Value Then
            'find the matching password
            If TextBox2.Text = chk.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                'check designations
                If chk.Offset(0, 2).Value = "ADMIN" Then
                    'your admin code here

                ElseIf chk.Offset(0, 2).Value = "USER" Then
                    'your user code here

                Else
                    MsgBox "Error: Failed to find designation, please consult admin!", vbCritical
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Else
                'error handling
                MsgBox "Error: You entered the incorrect password, please try again!", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        'error handling
        If chk.row = 100 Then
            MsgBox "Error: Could not match your User Name, please try again!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next chk

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! but our requirement needs to have role which is a admin and not an admin how can i identify from the code to have them as admin vice versa

Comment: @Chan please see edit. If this is what you are looking for please UV and mark as your answer to close the ticket.